# RTMP live stream in Expo React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, video-streaming, expo, rtmp

I'm trying to play the RTMP live streaming in the expo app. But unable to play. After research, I found Expo doesn't support RTMP protocol in expo-video, and to play RTMP video I have to eject expo from the app. My app is heavily dependent on expo so I don't want to eject.

Is there any way I can play RTMP live stream in my expo app?

Comment: didi. you find a solution for ur problem ? because i am having the same issue

Comment: @Kob_24 No, I had to eject expo and convert the app into react native cli then I used Nodemedia client for streaming.

Comment: use this one import { Video } from 'expo-av';
I used it and its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library in a project that is related.

`https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient`

Comment: But this library needs to eject the expo from app which I don't want

Comment: Hmm, maybe try [this] (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stuck on RTMP playback in Expo, it can now be done with the deprecated Node Media Client library as suggested above (https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient), but without having to fully eject.

I can confirm that Node Media Client works flawlessly with Expo's dev client  (https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/) while maintaining the benefit of a fully managed workflow in Expo and Expo Go. One caveat though, you will not be able to test any RTMP functionality in Expo Go, you will **need** to use a development build.